# erase a part of a string in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Let's say I have something like this:

`var location = '/users/45/messages/current/20/';`

and I need to end up with this:

`'/45/messages/current/20/'`

So, I need to erase the first part of `/whatever/`

I can use jquery and/or javascript. How would I do it in the best way possible?

Comment: Don't declare a `var location` as it can get confused with `window.location` depending on the scope.

Comment: Just note that by naming the variable `location`, it will shadow `window.location` (which of course you can always access via `window.location`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace everything up to the second slash:

```
var i = location.indexOf("/", 1); //Start at 2nd character to skip first slash
var result = location.substr(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions, or the possibly more readable

```
var location = '/users/45/messages/current/20/';
var delim = "/"
alert(delim+location.split(delim).slice(2).join(delim))
```

Comment: +1, split/slice/join is probably what I would go with.  Either that or the substr approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's slice() command. Do you need to parse for where to slice from or is it a known prefix? Depending on what exactly you are parsing for, it may be as simple as use match() to find your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.replace("/(whatever|you|want|users|something)/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

find the 2nd index of '/' in the string, then substr from the index to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
location.replace(/\/.*?\//, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to eliminate the first part of a relative path, it's probably simplest just to use regular expressions

```
var loc = '/users/45/messages/current/20/';
loc.replace(/^\/[^\/]+/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location.replace(/^\/[^\/]+/, '')
```